# DRF serializer validation depends on format of request?

Tags: json, django, validation, django-rest-framework, pytest

I tried to google this one up and still cannot find an answer. Maybe I am missing sth basic...
While testing a PUT and POST requests with pytest I have noticed that when I provide data with a missing serializer field it is ok - as long as I don't specify the format of the request.
The code is simply:

```
 class MySerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
        a = ...
        b = ....
        c = serializers.BooleanField(source='some_c')
def test():
    ...
    data = {'a': something, 'b': something_else} # 'c' is missing, c should be boolean
    resp = client.post(reverse('articles-list'), data=data, format='json')
```

... and I get HTTP 400, {'c': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}

when I omit the format part though, the test passes... The difference I can see is that if I skip the format, the request.data won't be a dict but a QueryDict instance

Comment: It would be helpful to see more context, for example the view you're using and what your tests are actually asserting that's passing/failing.

Comment: can you please add some detail to help me out to fix your problem